# Firebase failure in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-ios

what's wrong with this picture ?

```
 import firebase from 'firebase';

 onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(() => {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .catch(() => {
           this.setState({ error: 'Authentication Failed' });
          });
       });
 }
```

And so that we're clear:

Yes it's installed in the framework when I built the app. And yes I'm calling it on the same page where this is being executed. And yes the app runs fine without this section of code. there are no coding errors, nor logic errors.

If I wanted to a.) debug this bit of code how would I do that ? and b.) where would I add the console.log statement ? I know it has to live somewhere....like here >

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(console.log(email, password)) ??

Shouldn't a call like these to firebase work like this ?

Thanks ahead of time.

Miles.

Comment: This looks correct to my eyes. Are you experiencing a specific error?

Comment: Yeah, it's not calling firebase! Is there a way I can see the call somewhere ? And it's not ending up in the database!

Comment: Is firebase imported on the page?

Comment: Yes! It is. I just posted the most relevant part of the code. But yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oy! When I called the function to press the button I had set up. I had written onButtonPress instead of onPress....grrrrrrrrr! Sorry to bother everyone. All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add firebase to your application, there are specific steps mentioned on their [site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth). The site has information no how to call firebase for email authentication.